# $A^2=0\implies im(A)\subset Ker(A)\implies rank(A)\leq {n\over 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix.
$$A^2=0\implies im(A)\subset Ker(A)\implies rank(A)\leq {n\over 2}$$

I am working on a problem and if I can show this implication, the problem would be solved.

I am not 100% sure whether it is correct or not. Please point out the mistakes.

Let $x\in im(A)$ then there exist $y$ such that $Ay=x$ which implies $A^2y=Ax=0$ and hence $x\in Ker(A)$.

But I am not able to show why $im(A)\subset Ker(A)\implies rank(A)\leq n/2$

By rank nullity theorem we have $rank(A)+N(A)=n$ and since $im(A)\subset Ker(A)$, we have $rank(A)\leq N(A)$

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n = \text{rank}(A) + N(A) \ge 2 \ \text{rank}(A).$$

Comment: Feeling stupid. It was right there in front of me. Thank a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You have $rank(A)\le N(A)$.
Putting $N(A)=n-rank(A)$, we get:
$rank(A)\le n-rank(A)\implies 2rank(A)\le n\implies rank(A)\le n/2$